# Kotlin variance issue

Tags: kotlin, covariance, contravariance

I'm playing with the concept of a chain of Nodes, each of which have could have different input and output types (though the input/output types would all derive from a shared parent type), where data is passed from node to node and transformed along the way.  Here's an example:

```
open class Shape
open class Oval : Shape()
class Circle : Oval()

class NodeChain {
    val nodes: MutableList<Node<in Shape, out Shape>> = mutableListOf()

    fun node(n: Node<in Shape, out Shape>) {
        val prevNode = nodes.lastOrNull()
        nodes.add(n)
        prevNode?.nextNode = n::processInput
    }

    fun processInput(input: List<Shape>) {
        nodes[0].processInput(input)
    }
}

abstract class Node<InputType : Shape, OutputType : Shape> {
    var nextNode: Function1<List<OutputType>, Unit>? = null

    abstract fun processInput(input: List<InputType>)
}

class OvalNode : Node<Shape, Oval>() {
    override fun processInput(input: List<Shape>) {
        nextNode?.invoke(listOf(Oval()))
    }
}

class CircleNode : Node<Oval, Circle>() {
    override fun processInput(input: List<Oval>) {
        nextNode?.invoke(listOf(Circle()))
    }
}

val nodeChain = with (NodeChain()) {
    node(OvalNode())
    node(CircleNode()) // Error[1] here (listed below)
    this
}

Erorr[1]:
Type mismatch. 
Required:
Scratch_3.Node<in Scratch_3.Shape, out Scratch_3.Shape>
Found:
Scratch_3.CircleNode
```

You can see at the end there that I get an error: when trying to add a 'CircleNode' to the chain, it complains about expecting a `Node<in Shape, out Shape>` and doesn't allow a `CircleNode` (which is `Node<Oval, Circle>`).  My understanding of variance isn't strong enough to figure out what I need to achieve this (or if it's even possible?).  Is this possible?  Am I on the right track?

Comment: `in Shape` only allows supertypes of `Shape`, not subtypes.  `Node<Shape, Circle>` would work.  `Node<Oval, Shape>` would not.

Comment: thanks @LouisWasserman, so is there a way to achieve this?  Some other combination of in/out here?

Comment: I doubt you can have a `NodeChain` type like you want to.  The linkage structure in `Node` with its `nextNode` field works, but you can't have the `with` structure work like you want it to because the type allowed for the next node changes as you add more nodes. `Node` alone should work, and building chains of `Node`s directly without an intermediate type should work.

Comment: thanks @LouisWasserman, yeah creating and connecting the nodes (without any managing chain) does work fine, but was hoping to be able to leverage the 'Chain' to own the nodes and assemble them...I worried though it may not be possible :/

Answer (score 0):

The type `Node<in Shape, out Shape>` you use is equivalent to `Node<Shape, *>`. Thus you can only add types having an `InputType` of `Shape`. For your usecase you should use `Node<*, *>` for adding any extension of `Node`:

```
class NodeChain {
    val nodes: MutableList<Node<*, *>> = mutableListOf()

    fun node(n: Node<*, *>) {
        val prevNode = nodes.lastOrNull()
        nodes.add(n)
        prevNode?.nextNode = n::processInput
    }

    fun processInput(input: List<Shape>) {
        nodes[0].processInput(input)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tynn, I tried this previously but I get an error when trying to call processInput: `Type mismatch. Required: List<Nothing> Found: List<Scratch_3.Shape>
Projected type Scratch_3.Node<*, *> restricts use of
public abstract fun processInput(input: List<InputType>): Unit defined in Scratch_3.Node`

Comment: Do you have a contravariance left in your implementation?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no...It's just the code I pasted above but with all of the `in`/`out` removed from `NodeChain`.  `Node` didn't have any.  Is it working for you?  I'll check again.

Comment: The issue is, that `List<InputType>` has `InputType` on an _in_ possition. So the contravariance is implicitly given.